# Fetching Variable from views.py file to html file

Tags: django

I am writing a simple code to fetch the variable from HTML file.
Here is my code:

views.py file

```
def VariableView(request):
    context = {'firstName: Muhammad' , 'lastName: Khan'}

    return render(request, 'Variable.html',context)
```

Variable.html file:

```
<body>
    <h1>VARIABLE.HTML</h1>
    <h2>{{firstName | upper}}</h2>
</body>
```

I get an error at my console:

```
TypeError at /MyApp/variable/
context must be a dict rather than set.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/MyApp/variable/
Django Version: 3.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
context must be a dict rather than set.
Exception Location: C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\django\template\context.py, line 268, in make_context
Python Executable:  C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.9
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\DJango\\mysite',
 'C:\\Program '
 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Program '
 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program '
 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib',
 'C:\\Program '
 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0',
 'C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python37\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program '
 'Files\\WindowsApps\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_3.7.2544.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 29 Jul 2022 08:23:36 +0000
```

Comment: Try `context = {'firstName': 'Muhammad' , 'lastName': 'Khan'}`

Answer (score 1):

As stated in error message, you forget 4 `'`

```
def VariableView(request):
    context = {'firstName': 'Muhammad' , 'lastName': 'Khan'}

    return render(request, 'Variable.html',context)
```